# Extracting last-names from a vector of names in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a dataframe that contains U.S. Senator names and I need to extract just the last names so I can fuzzy match them with another dataframe that has other information about the senators, (and a column that contains just last names.)

The problem is that the names sometimes contain a middle initial or middle name and have the Senator's party at the end. How can I write a gsub command just to extract the Senator's last name? Apologies, I'm new to regex and really bad at it.

Snippet of the data here:

```
names <- c("John Kerry (D)", "John H Chafee (R)", "Chris Dodd (D)", "Joe Lieberman (D)", "Frank R Lautenberg (D)", "Daniel Patrick Moynihan (D)", "Alfonse M D'Amato (R)", "Arlen Specter (R)", "Jay Rockefeller (D)", "Carl Levin (D)")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `strsplit()` along with `lapply()` on the resulting list:

```
> unlist(lapply(strsplit(names, " "), function(x) { return(x[length(x)-1]) }))
 [1] "Kerry"       "Chafee"      "Dodd"        "Lieberman"   "Lautenberg"
 [6] "Moynihan"    "D'Amato"     "Specter"     "Rockefeller" "Levin"
```

The trick here is to take the second to last element in each splitted string, which is the last name.

Comment: So quick and so on point! Thank you! I was thinking about the 2nd element aspect, but I couldn't figure out the syntax. Thanks again!

Comment: You could use `"\\s+"` as the split too to account for the occasion when someone added an extra space character in there.

Answer (score 0):

This will parse out the names for you.

```
library(stringi)
library(rex)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

name_split = rex(capture(any_graphs), 
                     " ",
                     maybe(capture(any_graphs), 
                           " "),
                     capture(any_graphs),
                     " ",
                     "(", capture(upper), ")")

data_frame(string = names) %>%
  extract(string, c("first", "middle", "last", "party"), name_split) %>%
  filter(first %>% is.na %>% `!`)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option with `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract(names, regex="\\w+(?=\\s+\\()")
#[1] "Kerry"       "Chafee"      "Dodd"        "Lieberman"   "Lautenberg" 
#[6] "Moynihan"    "Amato"       "Specter"     "Rockefeller" "Levin"
```